# Div with image inside div to not interfere with text?

Tags: css, image, html, textures

I am trying to insert a div with an image inside of another div which has text in it. I have set the z-align so that the main div with text in it is above.

The div with an image is merely to add a texture to the background of the first div.

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks.

Here is the relevant code:

CSS:

```
    #websiteBG2 {
opacity:0.2;
width:100%;
border-radius:15px;
z-align:1;

}



    #textboxdiv {
    font: 15px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 700px;
height: 600px;
border-radius:15px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(255,255,0,0.9);  
background-color:#08298A;
opacity:0.8;
text-align:center;
margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
z-align:2;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="textboxdiv">
<br>
Introducing ----, a game created by ----.

<div id="websiteBG2">
<img src="websiteBG2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div id="textboxdiv">
    <div id="div_txt">
       <br>
        Introducing ----, a game created by ----.
     </div>

    <div id="websiteBG2">
        <img src="images.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

in css file

```
#div_txt
{
position:absolute;
}
#websiteBG2 {
opacity:0.2;
width:100%;
border-radius:15px;
z-align:1;
}



#textboxdiv {
font: 15px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 700px;
height: 600px;
border-radius:15px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(255,255,0,0.9);  
background-color:#08298A;
opacity:0.8;
text-align:center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
z-align:2;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I can't seem to align the text for the #div_txt. I tried text-align:center; of course, but had no luck with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a background image in CSS:

`background-image: url('<path to file'>);`

What you're doing at the moment is just inserting a regular image into a div, not a background image.

Comment: While doing this, will I be able to set the opacity for the background-image?

Comment: Hmm and after trying what you suggested, it appears it isn't really what I'm looking for. I currently have a blue background for the main text div. I want the other div behind that to give it a blue texture with the image.

Comment: Set the background image of the main text div to use the texture image then. There's no need to have one div just for a background image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="textboxdiv">
    <br>Introducing ----, a game created by ----.
    <div id="websiteBG2">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#websiteBG2 {
    opacity:0.2;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:15px;
    z-align:1;
}
#textboxdiv {
    font: 15px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 700px;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius:15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
    background-color:#08298A;
    opacity:0.8;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-align:2;
}
#textboxdiv:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmCZItwkhIcWH_uG0WQRNfs63BTRIcOHrme2TxcDb1jZLJ7nkhpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    opacity: 0.1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/5mDR4/1/)

**EDIT:** I've edited the CSS to make the background iamge translucent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but ideally I'm looking to use the texture I already have.

Comment: @user3227878 so change the URL with your image's URL.